# Getting multiple errors when inserting power query into macro, "query with name already exists", "select method of range class failed"

Tags: vba, powerquery

First off, I am a beginner in VBA and Power Query, so I am somewhat stumbling through this process.

I have a macro that includes a power query (that takes an existing data set and creates a table, deleting the rest of the dataset).  I ran it one time successfully, and then it started throwing an  a run-time error "A query with the name 'Table1' already exists'.  Here is the vba code, excluding a section before the power query bit that creates custom columns needed for the query to run -

Range("A1:EJ500").Select

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$EJ$500"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table1", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Table1""]}[Content]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Interviewer Last Name"", type text}, {""CMR used for family"", type any}, {""LHD Investigation Completed"", type datetime}, {""QT Day Zero based on Last HH Onset"", type datetime}, {""Test 1"", type text}, {""Test 2"", type text}, {""" & _
    "Test 3"", type text}, {""Test 4"", type text}, {""Test 5"", type text}, {""Test 6"", type text}, {""Test 7"", type text}, {""Test 8"", type text}, {""Test 9"", type text}, {""Test 10"", type text}, {""Test 11"", type text}, {""Test 12"", type text}, {""Test 13"", type text}, {""Test 14"", type text}, {""Test 15"", type text}, {""Test 16"", type text}, {""Household C" & _
    "ontact CMR Field 1"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 1"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 1"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 1"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Status "", type text}, {""School District 1"", type text}, {""School Name 1"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 1"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 1"", type datetime}" & _
    ", {""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 1"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 1"", type text}, {""HH onset date"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact CMR Field 2"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 2"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 2"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 2"", type datetime}, {""Househo" & _
    "ld Contact Status 2"", type text}, {""School District 2"", type text}, {""School Name 2"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 2"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 2"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 2"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 2"", type text}, {""HH onset date3"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact" & _
    " CMR Field 3"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 3"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 3"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 3"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Status 4"", type text}, {""School District 3"", type text}, {""School Name 3"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 3"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 3"", type datetime}, {""" & _
    "Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 3"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 3"", type text}, {""HH onset date5"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact CMR Field 4"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 4"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 4"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 4"", type datetime}, {""Household C" & _
    "ontact Status 6"", type text}, {""School District "", type text}, {""School Name "", type text}, {""Staff or Student "", type text}, {""Date Last Attended "", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 4"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 4"", type text}, {""HH onset date7"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact CMR Fie" & _
    "ld 5"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 5"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 5"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 5"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Status 8"", type text}, {""School District 9"", type text}, {""School Name 10"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 11"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 12"", type datetime}, {""House" & _
    "hold Contact Date of Last Exposure 5"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 5"", type text}, {""HH onset date13"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact CMR Field 6"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 6"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 6"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 6"", type datetime}, {""Household Conta" & _
    "ct Status 14"", type text}, {""School District 15"", type text}, {""School Name 16"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 17"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 18"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 6"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 6"", type text}, {""HH onset date19"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact C" & _
    "MR Field 7"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 7"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 7"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 7"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Status 20"", type text}, {""School District 21"", type text}, {""School Name 22"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 23"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 24"", type datetime}, " & _
    "{""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 7"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 7"", type text}, {""HH onset date25"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact CMR Field 8"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 8"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 8"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 8"", type datetime}, {""Househo" & _
    "ld Contact Status 26"", type text}, {""School District 27"", type text}, {""School Name 28"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 29"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 30"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 8"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 8"", type text}, {""HH onset date31"", type datetime}, {""Household C" & _
    "ontact CMR Field 9"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 9"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 9"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 9"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Status 32"", type text}, {""School District 33"", type text}, {""School Name 34"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 35"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 36"", type dat" & _
    "etime}, {""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 9"", type any}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 9"", type any}, {""HH onset date37"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact CMR Field 10"", Int64.Type}, {""Household Contact First Name 10"", type text}, {""Household Contact Last Name 10"", type text}, {""Household Contact DOB 10"", type datetime}, {""H" & _
    "ousehold Contact Status 38"", type text}, {""School District 39"", type text}, {""School Name 40"", type text}, {""Staff or Student 41"", type text}, {""Date Last Attended 42"", type datetime}, {""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 10"", type any}, {""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 10"", type any}, {""HH onset date43"", type datetime}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Re" & _
    "placed Value"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Changed Type"",null,"""",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{""Interviewer Last Name"", ""CMR used for family"", ""LHD Investigation Completed"", ""QT Day Zero based on Last HH Onset"", ""Test 1"", ""Test 2"", ""Test 3"", ""Test 4"", ""Test 5"", ""Test 6"", ""Test 7"", ""Test 8"", ""Test 9"", ""Test 10"", ""Test 11"", ""Test 12"", ""Test 13" & _
    """, ""Test 14"", ""Test 15"", ""Test 16"", ""Household Contact CMR Field 1"", ""Household Contact First Name 1"", ""Household Contact Last Name 1"", ""Household Contact DOB 1"", ""Household Contact Status "", ""School District 1"", ""School Name 1"", ""Staff or Student 1"", ""Date Last Attended 1"", ""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 1"", ""Household Contact " & _
    "Ongoing Exposure Question 1"", ""HH onset date"", ""Household Contact CMR Field 2"", ""Household Contact First Name 2"", ""Household Contact Last Name 2"", ""Household Contact DOB 2"", ""Household Contact Status 2"", ""School District 2"", ""School Name 2"", ""Staff or Student 2"", ""Date Last Attended 2"", ""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 2"", ""Household " & _
    "Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 2"", ""HH onset date3"", ""Household Contact CMR Field 3"", ""Household Contact First Name 3"", ""Household Contact Last Name 3"", ""Household Contact DOB 3"", ""Household Contact Status 4"", ""School District 3"", ""School Name 3"", ""Staff or Student 3"", ""Date Last Attended 3"", ""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 3"", ""H" & _
    "ousehold Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 3"", ""HH onset date5"", ""Household Contact CMR Field 4"", ""Household Contact First Name 4"", ""Household Contact Last Name 4"", ""Household Contact DOB 4"", ""Household Contact Status 6"", ""School District "", ""School Name "", ""Staff or Student "", ""Date Last Attended "", ""Household Contact Date of Last Exposure 4""" & _
    ", ""Household Contact Ongoing Exposure Question 4"", ""HH onset date7"", ""Household Contact CMR Field 5"", ""Household Contact First Name 5"", ""Household Contact Last Name 5"", ""Household Contact DOB 5"", ""Household Contact Status 8"", ""School District 9"", ""School Name 10"", ""Staff or Student 11"", ""Date Last Attended 12"", ""Household Contact Date of Last " & _
    ""


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table1"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table1__2"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

In order to fix the query name issue, I inserted this at the beginning, right after "Range("A1:EJ500").Select" -

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Table1").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
wb.Activate
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Sheet1[#All]").Select
```

Then running the macro started giving me a "run-time error 1004, the name 'Source' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly."  So I modified Range("Table1[#All]").Select to "wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[#All]").Select" based off of reading other posts, and now I get "run-time error 1004. Select method of Range class failed."  I tried modifying that and I just continue to get those same errors, so I'm starting to get confused about where the problem is.

Any assistance?

Comment: in your debugging code, you use `ActiveWorkbook` and `wb`. Can you confirm they are the same workbook? You also have `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Sheet1[#All]").Select`, this can be written as `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select`. Though I'm not sure why this line is included at all... Selecting cells is only useful for drawing a user's attention to them.

Comment: The original code I posted that includes "ActiveWorkbook" and the "Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Sheet1[#All]").Select" came from instructions I found online regarding how to add a power query to vba code.  I made some changes (like the "wb") based on other posts I found after getting those errors.  I'm happy to change whatever in order to make this work.  I changed that line to "Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Sheet1[#All]").Select", and now I'm getting a run-time 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error."

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select` instead of `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Sheet1[#All]").Select`.

Comment: That got me back to run-time error 1004, the name 'Source' wasn't recognized."  Although now the debug highlights the second to last line - ".Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False".

Comment: Yes, you had two errors, and I was just suggesting a solution to one. The other one involves powerquery which I do not know.

Comment: You mentioned that you do not know the location of the error. The code responsible for the error should be this argument `Source:= "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table1"";Extended Properties="""""`